# Get the featured image of an ACF relationship field

Tags: post-thumbnails, advanced-custom-fields

I have an Advanced Custom Fields field group with ID `group_61318c077c7d6`. I've made this field group visible for Block = 'slider'.

In that field group is a field with ID `field_61318c078a746`, a relationship field with a relationship to a custom post type called `templates`.

I’d like to create a Gutenberg slider block like [this one](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/building-a-custom-slider-block-in-30-minutes-with-acf/), which loops over the rows of `group_61318c077c7d6` and grabs the image from `Image` image field of the `field_61318c078a746’s` related templates.

So, something like:

```
<div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($className); ?>">
    <?php if( have_rows('group_61318c077c7d6') ) { ?>
        <?php echo 'we have rows';?>
        <div class="slides">
        <?php while( have_rows('group_61318c077c7d6') ) {
            the_row();
        }
        $templates = get_sub_field('field_61318c078a746'); //should return a post object
        if ( $templates ) { ?>
            <div>
            <?php foreach ($templates as $template) {
                $template_featured_image = get_field('Image', $template);
                echo '<img src="' . $template_featured_image . '" />';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>Please add some slides.</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

When I add the block to a page, I see the `group_61318c077c7d6` field group in the sidebar, and I can select 'templates' within the relationship selector, but no images are displayed in the slider block, **because `<?php if( have_rows('group_61318c077c7d6') ) { ?>` is returning false**, even though I see this field group in the slider block's properties sidebar.

How do I complete this code to grab the featured image of the `field_61318c078a746’s` related post, please?

These are the ACF fields of the Templates field group, which are attached to the templates custom post type:

[image]

Help appreciated.

Comment: Just curious to know if there is a specific reason to use the group ids instead of field names to get the values?

Also, just to be sure does the block gets printed at all? Do you see the wrapper div on the page? `<div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class=""`

Comment: You're right, I don't need to use the group id. I do see the wrapper div. With Caleb's solution below there are no images displaying, they are being output as `<img src="">`, @Kumar

Answer (score 1):

According to [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/#template-usage), a `foreach` loop is to be used to access the items in a Relationship field.

Untested:

```php
$templates = get_field( 'field_61318c078a746' );

foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
    $template_image_id  = absint( get_field( 'Image', $template ) );
    $template_image_url = 'https://example.com/fallback-image.jpg';

    if ( ! empty( $template_image_id ) ) {
        $template_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $template_image_id, 'large' );
    }

    ...
}
```

In most use cases you will not need to interact with field groups on the frontend. There are occasions for it, but very few in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. The problem is that `<?php if( have_rows('group_61318c077c7d6') ) { ?><?php echo 'we have rows';?>` echoes nothing.

Comment: Please try the code supplied in my answer: you shouldn't need to use the group at all.

Comment: Thanks. I was wrong; the images are not featured images, but set in a field called `Image`. At the moment, the slider images are being output as `<img src="8514">`. Switching to `$template_featured_image = get_field('Image', $template);` produces `<img src="">`

Comment: If you have the ID 8514 you can look that up with wp_get_attachment_image_url or wp_get_attachment_image_src etc., or wp_get_attachment_image for the full HTML img tag

Comment: Updated answer.